# What happens 'internally' on a unstable/overclocked/undervolted CPU?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

When you undervolt or overlock an CPU, when it passes a certain limit it starts to make the system unstable, reboot, etc. But these are the effects of it.

What I'm curious about is what happens on the CPU. What happens? It gives wrong answers to instructions? Bits on cache flip?

Comment: A CPU is made of transistors.  If to much power or to little power is provided to these transistors, performance is unpredictable, there are extreme in which performance will eventually suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All logic in digital electronics is basically made up of transistors. The zero and one states have certain thresholds that define what the are. For example if your transistors are run at 1.8V, there may be a definition that 0-0.75V is logical zero and 1.05-1.8V is logical one. There may also be different values for input and output, but let's simplify.

Any value that is between these is unknown, since we don't want there to be a case when the values can be either one with unknown probability.

Now, when you undervolt the transistors you are reducing the value area, especially in the logical one part. The transistors might give you 0.9V for logical one and that is not accepted, therefore resulting in an error state. Depends on the design and circuit how this manifests. It could be in a memory chip and might cause a zero to be stored. It could be in a calculation instruction inside the CPU and cause false result. Or it could be a bit that is never used, or happily understood as logical one and you never even notice it was there.

Comment: This has been around a while, but I figure what the heck, why not add more! What can happen with over-clocking is a timing constraint is violated. A signal which had to be stable before some interval failed to reach the "correct" / "final" value in time because some other part was expecting it too soon. Signal propagation can also be an issue - the signal had to travel through some number of gates, and each gate slowed down the result too much.